# How to insert spreadsheet (ODS or XLSX) to text document (ODT or DOCX) via api

Tags: api, libreoffice, openoffice.org

I have a text document (ODT or DOCX) and a spreadsheet (ODS or XLSX). I use LibreOffice API (in Java) to open this document.

I want to insert a spreadsheet into text document as embedded object. I can do it manually (via GUI LibreOffice Writer - menu Insert\Object\OLE Object), but I need this via API.
P.S. Official documentation for LibreOffice (OpenOffice) API is very poor. In this very interesting article http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jlop/ this information is not found.

Comment: Good job writing your first two questions.  They are both clear and show research effort.

Answer (score 0):

The following Basic code is given at https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/76781/create-macro-to-insert-and-link-a-ole-spreadsheet/:

```vb
Sub oleexample
    oDoc = ThisComponent
    txt=oDoc.getText
    obj = oDoc.createInstance("com.sun.star.text.TextEmbeddedObject")
    obj.CLSID = "47BBB4CB-CE4C-4E80-a591-42d9ae74950f"
    obj.attach(ThisComponent.currentController().Selection.getByIndex(0))
    oXEO = obj.ExtendedControlOverEmbeddedObject
    oXEO.doVerb(0)
End Sub
```

There is also an example at https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=14342 that embeds a Math object.